# Use new Input Model in .net WebBrowser on Windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control, internet-explorer-11

I have a .net WebBrowser control, and I want it to use the *Windows 8 Input Model* for IE in Windows 7 (with Internet Explorer 11).

**Does anyone have ideas or know how to enable the new Input Model? Is it possible?**

On Windows 8, this is possible by setting the registry key FEATURE_NINPUT_LEGACYMODE = 0
however on Windows 7 this does not seem to work.

*Note: Naming my process to iexplore.exe will make it work, so it should be possible somehow.*

**ps**. There is an issue posted here https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/867621/ but I could not get the workaround to work on my system.